# JQuery AJAX function not receiving PHP-returned text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been searching for a while for a solution to this problem.  I've found many people with the same problem, but not the same solution.

The issue I'm having is that PHP is not returning any data to the AJAX function.  The alert spits out `data = undefined`.  As you can see, using `return` instead of `echo` is not the problem.  I know that the PHP script I call completes correctly because the values are properly inserted into the database.  No matter where I place the echo statement, I can't get it to return the value.  Am I using the `data` variable incorrectly?  Is `returnValue` not the proper variable to use?  Has any of the functionality I've been trying to use been deprecated?  I'm really at a complete loss.  I can't see why this is failing.

//AJAX function

```
$("document").ready(function(){

        $("#add_interest_form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#output").html("");

            var values = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax
            ({
                url: "./php/add_interest.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: values,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('data = ' + data.returnValue);
                    $("#output").html(data.returnValue);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('failed adding to database.  Please try again or contact the Webmaster.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

//PHP snippet
`echo 'Success!';`

Comment: What do you get if you just alert `data` instead of `data.returnValue`?

Comment: contents of `add_interest.php`?

Comment: And please change $("document") to $(document) as document is not a DOM Element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `alert('data = ' + data);` instead of `alert('data = ' + data.returnValue);`.

Comment: Finally!  That worked.  Fastest correct answer I've ever gotten on SO.  So fast that SO won't let me accept your answer for another 5 minutes.